# SmsReceiver BroadcastReceiver issues

Tags: android

I have been trying to get SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver to work on a HTC Desire HD.

I have no program for my Msgs downloaded, just using what the phone gave me.

I have a log just under the onReceive function and i never see it.

Reasonably new to this so any help would be great :) thanks

Java class

---

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
Log.d("SIM", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
Toast.makeText(context, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
}
}
```

---

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.b.smspopup"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>  


<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name=".Main" >
<intent-filter >
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>                

</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

---

LogCat log below

---

```
01-11 13:43:50.078: D/Jerry(1438): messageRef >182
01-11 13:43:50.078: D/Jerry(1438): ackPDU >null
01-11 13:43:50.078: D/Jerry(1438): errorCode >-1
01-11 13:43:50.078: D/Jerry(1438): handleMessage >2
01-11 13:43:50.178: D/Jerry(1438): handleMessage >1
01-11 13:43:50.178: D/SMSDispatcher(1438): dispatchWapPushToCIQ  >>>
01-11 13:43:50.178: D/SMSDispatcher(1438): dispatchWapPushToCIQ  >>>
01-11 13:43:50.228: V/SmsReceiverService(8697): onStart: #1
01-11 13:43:50.238: V/SmsReceiverService(8697): action: android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
01-11 13:43:50.238: D/SmsReceiverService(8697): [HTC_MESSAGES] - SmsReceiverService: handleSmsReceived()
01-11 13:43:50.238: D/SmsReceiverService(8697): isEvdo: false  before inserMessage
01-11 13:43:50.238: D/SmsReceiverService(8697): extractContentValues: not EVDO
01-11 13:43:50.238: D/SmsReceiverService(8697): MsgBase: from Evdo: false
01-11 13:43:50.238: D/SmsProvider(1438): insert url=content://sms/inbox, match=2
01-11 13:43:50.248: D/SmsProvider(1438): thread id> null
01-11 13:43:50.248: D/MmsSmsProvider(1438): ids: 73
01-11 13:43:50.248: D/MmsSmsProvider(1438): recipientIds: 73
01-11 13:43:50.248: D/SmsProvider(1438): get thread id> 114
01-11 13:43:50.278: D/MmsSmsV2Provider(1438): Notify ContactMessageStore new thread have been created
01-11 13:43:50.278: D/ContactMessageStore(1438): insertContactsTable> 114, 0
01-11 13:43:50.278: D/ContactMessageStore(1438): getContactsTableStr> contacts1
01-11 13:43:50.278: D/ContactMessageStore(1438): insertContactsTable() 114, 98 already exist
01-11 13:43:50.278: D/MmsSmsDatabaseHelper(1438): refreshThreadsTable: 114
01-11 13:43:50.448: D/MmsSmsDatabaseHelper(1438): refreshThreadsTable count: 1
01-11 13:43:50.458: D/SmsReceiverService(8697): insertUri> content://sms/2287
01-11 13:43:50.458: D/SmsReceiverService(8697): class: UNKNOWN
01-11 13:43:50.458: D/Messaging(8697): accumulateNewIncomingMSG> 2
01-11 13:43:50.468: D/MmsSmsProvider(1438): ids: 73
01-11 13:43:50.468: D/MmsSmsProvider(1438): recipientIds: 73
01-11 13:43:50.478: V/Recycler(8697): Recycler.deleteOldMessagesByThreadId this: com.android.mms.util.Recycler$SmsRecycler@4054c2c0 threadId: 114
01-11 13:43:50.478: D/MessagingNotification(8697): New incoming message, can't cancel notification now
01-11 13:43:50.478: D/MessagingNotification(8697): newMsgCnt: 2, true
01-11 13:43:50.518: D/MessagingNotification(8697): Thread id > 114
01-11 13:43:50.518: D/MessagingNotification(8697): Contact id > 100000098
01-11 13:43:50.518: D/MessagingNotification(8697): Unread count: 18, 2
01-11 13:43:50.518: D/MessagingNotification(8697): updateNotification> 
01-11 13:43:50.518: E/xxxx!!(8697): ringtoneStr= content://media/internal/audio/media/3
01-11 13:43:50.528: D/MessagingNotification(8697): getValidNotificationUri> content://media/internal/audio/media/3
01-11 13:43:50.548: D/NotificationFlashLightUtility getIncomingCall(8697): load fail~~~~~~~~~~
01-11 13:43:50.548: D/MessagingNotification(8697): show notification
01-11 13:43:50.548: D/MessagingNotification(8697): notifyNotification> 123
01-11 13:43:50.548: D/MessagingNotification(8697): threadID> 114
01-11 13:43:50.548: D/MessagingNotification(8697): addItemIntoIdList> [114]
01-11 13:43:50.548: D/StatusBarService(31423): old notification: when=1326250052000 ongoing=false expanded=android.widget.LinearLayout@4058e5e0 contentView=android.widget.RemoteViews@4058bcf0
01-11 13:43:50.548: D/StatusBarService(31423): new notification: when=1326250098000 ongoing=false contentView=android.widget.RemoteViews@406b7200
01-11 13:43:50.568: D/MediaPlayer(1326): setDataSource(Context context, content://media/internal/audio/media/3, Map<String, String> headers) in
01-11 13:43:50.568: D/lights(1326): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/amber/brightness string=0,len=1
01-11 13:43:50.568: D/lights(1326): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/amber/blink string=0,len=1
01-11 13:43:50.568: D/lights(1326): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/amber/off_timer string=0 0,len=3
01-11 13:43:50.568: V/NotificationService(1326): Battery Full, Charging
01-11 13:43:50.578: D/lights(1326): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/green/brightness string=1,len=1
01-11 13:43:50.578: D/lights(1326): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/green/blink string=0,len=1
01-11 13:43:50.578: D/lights(1326): [LedInfo] write attr ok name=/sys/class/leds/green/off_timer string=0 0,len=3
01-11 13:43:50.588: D/MediaPlayer(1326): setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd) in
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): Client(1662) constructor
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): Create new client(1662) from pid 1326, fd=41, offset=0, length=576460752303423487, audioSessionId=1787
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): setDataSource fd=41, offset=0, length=576460752303423487
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): st_dev  = 45849
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): st_mode = 33188
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): st_uid  = 0
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): st_gid  = 0
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): st_size = 5697
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): calculated length = 5697
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): player type = 4
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/MediaPlayerService(1230):  create StagefrightPlayer
01-11 13:43:50.588: V/AudioSink(1230): AudioOutput(1787)
01-11 13:43:50.588: D/MediaPlayer(1326): setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd) out
01-11 13:43:50.588: D/MediaPlayer(1326): setDataSource(Context context, content://media/internal/audio/media/3, Map<String, String> headers) out
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): [1662] setLooping(0)
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): [1662] setAudioStreamType(5)
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): [1662] prepareAsync
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): [1662] notify (0x4d0c8, 5, 0, 0)
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): [1662] notify (0x4d0c8, 1, 0, 0)
01-11 13:43:50.598: I/AudioService(1326):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@40792038
01-11 13:43:50.598: D/MediaPlayer(1326): start() in
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): [1662] setLooping(0)
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): [1662] setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/AudioSink(1230): setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): [1662] setAuxEffectSendLevel(0.000000)
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/AudioSink(1230): setAuxEffectSendLevel(0.000000)
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): [1662] start    01-11 13:43:50.598: V/AudioSink(1230): open(44100, 1, 1, 4, 1787)
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/AudioSink(1230): setVolume
01-11 13:43:50.598: V/AudioSink(1230): start
01-11 13:43:50.608: D/AudioFlinger(1230): [AudioFlinger::MixerThread::threadLoop] set ALC to enable
01-11 13:43:50.608: D/MediaPlayer(1326): start() out
01-11 13:43:50.608: D/MediaPlayer(1326): release() in
01-11 13:43:50.608: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): disconnect(1661) from pid 1326
01-11 13:43:50.608: V/AudioSink(1230): stop
01-11 13:43:50.608: V/AudioSink(1230): close
01-11 13:43:50.608: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): Client(1661) destructor pid = 1326
01-11 13:43:50.608: V/AudioSink(1230): close
01-11 13:43:50.608: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): disconnect(1661) from pid 1326
01-11 13:43:50.608: D/MediaPlayer(1326): release() out
01-11 13:43:50.608: D/ConversationListBaseActivity(8697): onNewNotification> 123, mIsForeground> false
01-11 13:43:50.618: D/StreamProcess(1230): +ProcessAOLC ResetAOLC delta=44888 @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
01-11 13:43:50.618: D/StreamProcess(1230): OutputStreamProcess::ResetAOLC()
01-11 13:43:50.618: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): acquire output wakelock
01-11 13:43:50.618: I/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): do_aic3254_control (1, 0, 0)
01-11 13:43:50.618: I/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): aic3254: change rx mode to 13
01-11 13:43:50.628: D/MessagingNotification(8697): Notify notification complete, can cancel notification now
01-11 13:43:50.628: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): addToTable (dec_id 5, dev_rx 6, dev_tx -1, type 1, active 1)
01-11 13:43:50.638: D/MessagingNotification(8697): New message
01-11 13:43:50.678: I/HTC Acoustic(1230): update ACDB id: (tx, rx, tx_acdb, rx_acdb) = (11, 6, 0, 607)
01-11 13:43:50.678: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): updateACDB: (6, 11, 607, 0) success!
01-11 13:43:50.678: I/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): AUDIO_START: start kernel pcm_out driver.
01-11 13:43:51.138: D/MessagingShortcut(8697): updateMsgShortcut, msg count> 2
01-11 13:43:51.138: D/MessagingShortcut(8697): mPresentUnreadCount: 1
01-11 13:43:51.138: D/MessagingShortcut(8697): setMsgShortcutDrawable> 2
01-11 13:43:51.258: E/MP3Extractor(1230): Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.
01-11 13:43:51.258: V/MediaPlayerService(1230): [1662] notify (0x4d0c8, 2, 0, 0)
01-11 13:43:51.258: V/AudioSink(1230): stop
01-11 13:43:51.258: I/AudioService(1326):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@40792038
01-11 13:43:51.408: D/MessagingShortcut(8697): Send UNREAD_MESSAGE_COUNT broadcast: count=2
01-11 13:43:54.148: D/SurfaceFlinger(1326): layer=0x13f4d88 is not in the purgatory list
01-11 13:43:54.368: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): release output wakelock
01-11 13:43:54.368: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): deleteFromTable, type 1
01-11 13:43:54.368: I/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): do_aic3254_control (1, 0, 1)
01-11 13:43:54.368: I/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): aic3254: change rx mode to 29
01-11 13:43:54.418: I/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): disable current rx device = 6
01-11 13:43:54.638: I/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1230): AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
01-11 13:43:54.638: D/StreamProcess(1230): OutputStreamProcess::ResetAOLC()
01-11 13:43:55.828: D/StatusBarPolicy(31423): onSignalStrengthsChanged
01-11 13:44:04.828: D/StatusBarPolicy(31423): onSignalStrengthsChanged
01-11 13:44:07.818: D/StatusBarPolicy(31423): onSignalStrengthsChanged
01-11 13:44:11.828: D/TrafficAppWidgetUpdateService(7536): Got widget id to update: 8
01-11 13:44:11.848: D/TrafficAppWidgetUpdateService(7536): Scheduled update for 8 in 29 s.
01-11 13:44:11.848: W/TrafficAppWidgetUpdateService(7536): Requested widget update, but no data found for id: 8
01-11 13:44:11.858: D/TrafficAppWidgetUpdateService(7536): No longer requesting location updates.
01-11 13:44:12.908: D/dalvikvm(7618): GC_EXPLICIT freed 350K, 46% free 4417K/8071K, external 0K/0K, paused 75ms
01-11 13:44:16.818: D/StatusBarPolicy(31423): onSignalStrengthsChanged
01-11 13:44:19.808: D/StatusBarPolicy(31423): onSignalStrengthsChanged
01-11 13:44:20.548: D/ContactMessageStore(1438): MSG_NOTIFY_CS_TO_SYNC >>
01-11 13:44:20.558: D/ContactMessageStore(1438): MSG_NOTIFY_CS_TO_SYNC <<
01-11 13:44:22.808: D/StatusBarPolicy(31423): onSignalStrengthsChanged
01-11 13:44:27.878: D/dalvikvm(7582): GC_EXPLICIT freed 173K, 46% free 3706K/6791K, external 0K/0K, paused 57ms
01-11 13:44:28.798: D/StatusBarPolicy(31423): onSignalStrengthsChanged
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit the content in application tag to this:

```
<application
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Main" >
    <intent-filter >
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>

 <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>                

</application>
```

I don't think u can mix activity and receiver tags

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much... As i said i am reasonably new to this but that worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest file is wrong.
Follow this http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: I have been working through a lot of stuff on that site recently, plan to keep going. Thanks!